# Why is variable1 += variable2 much faster than variable1 = variable1 + variable2?

Tags: python, html, string, performance, python-internals

I have inherited some Python code which is used to create huge tables (of up to 19 columns wide by 5000 rows). It took **nine seconds** for the table to be drawn on the screen. I noticed that each row was added using this code:

```
sTable = sTable + '\n' + GetRow()
```

where `sTable` is a string.

I changed that to:

```
sTable += '\n' + GetRow()
```

and I noticed that the table now appeared in **six seconds**.

And then I changed it to:

```
sTable += '\n%s' % GetRow()
```

based on [these Python performance tips](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#String_Concatenation) (still six seconds).

Since this was called about 5000 times, it highlighted the performance issue. But why was there such a large difference? And why didn't the compiler spot the problem in the first version and optimise it?

Comment: With no static types, there's very little opportunity for the kind of compile-time optimizations you might be used to from languages like C, and CPython doesn't have a JIT. Also, `+=` has distinct effects from `+` and `=`, so it'd take some extra analysis to determine what other references to `sTable` exist.

Comment: Concatenating strings is slow. You might want to use the [canonical way](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) and gather your rows in a list and [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) them after you got all of them: `table = ''.join(rows)`.

Comment: timing it on 100k concats, `+=` is is `.06ms` faster using python 2.7.8

Comment: Thanks @Matthias - I tried that as well (see also the linked question) but that made no performance difference, surprisingly.

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham: You might have a strange test setup. I added a random text of 10 characters 5000 times. Running the tests 1000 times i get 16.7 seconds with `+=` and 0.1 seconds with `join`.

Comment: @Wikis, I was on about `s +=` vs `s = s + `

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: the speed difference varies with runs, but comes down to no real speed change at all. But that's because the OP initially failed to mention that there are **three** strings involved per concatenation. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters, yep, it was definitely not from joining two strings. That little extra bit of information does make a difference :)

Comment: Why is this question suddenly getting many upvotes in the last 24 hours?

Comment: @Wikis: see [10 Million Questions - Let's Share Some Stories That the Number Doesn't Convey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303045)

Comment: @MartijnPieters, great to see your recognition for this answer, thanks!

Answer (score 91, accepted):

This isn't about using inplace `+=` versus `+` binary add. You didn't tell us the whole story. Your original version concatenated 3 strings, not just two:

```
sTable = sTable + '\n' + sRow  # simplified, sRow is a function call
```

Python tries to help out and optimises string concatenation; both when using `strobj += otherstrobj` and `strobj = strobj + otherstringobj`, but it cannot apply this optimisation when more than 2 strings are involved.

Python strings are immutable **normally**, but if there are no other references to the left-hand string object *and* it is being rebound anyway, then Python cheats and *mutates the string*. This avoids having to create a new string each time you concatenate, and that can lead to a big speed improvement.

This is implemented in the bytecode evaluation loop. Both when using [`BINARY_ADD` on two strings](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/23a60d89dbd4/Python/ceval.c#l1202) and when using [`INPLACE_ADD` on two strings](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/23a60d89dbd4/Python/ceval.c#l1406), Python delegates concatenation to a special helper function [`string_concatenate()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/23a60d89dbd4/Python/ceval.c#l4507). To be able to optimize the concatenation by mutating the string, it first needs to make sure that the string has no other references to it; if only the stack and the original variable reference it then this can be done, **and** the **next** operation is going to replace the original variable reference.

So if there are just 2 references to the string, and the next operator is one of `STORE_FAST` (set a local variable), `STORE_DEREF` (set a variable referenced by closed over functions) or `STORE_NAME` (set a global variable), and the affected variable currently references the same string, then that target variable is cleared to reduce the number of references to just 1, the stack.

And this is why your original code could not use this optimization fully. The first part of your expression is `sTable + '\n'` and the *next* operation is *another `BINARY_ADD`*:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(compile(r"sTable = sTable + '\n' + sRow", '<stdin>', 'exec'))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (sTable)
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 ('\n')
              6 BINARY_ADD          
              7 LOAD_NAME                1 (sRow)
             10 BINARY_ADD          
             11 STORE_NAME               0 (sTable)
             14 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             17 RETURN_VALUE
```

The first `BINARY_ADD` is followed by a `LOAD_NAME` to access the `sRow` variable, not a store operation. This first `BINARY_ADD` must always result in a new string object, ever larger as `sTable` grows and it takes more and more time to create this new string object.

You changed this code to:

```
sTable += '\n%s' % sRow
```

which **removed the second concatenation**. Now the bytecode is:

```
>>> dis.dis(compile(r"sTable += '\n%s' % sRow", '<stdin>', 'exec'))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (sTable)
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 ('\n%s')
              6 LOAD_NAME                1 (sRow)
              9 BINARY_MODULO       
             10 INPLACE_ADD         
             11 STORE_NAME               0 (sTable)
             14 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             17 RETURN_VALUE
```

and all we have left is an `INPLACE_ADD` followed by a store. Now `sTable` can be altered in-place, not resulting in a ever larger new string object.

You'd have gotten the same speed difference with:

```
sTable = sTable + ('\n%s' % sRow)
```

here.

A time trial shows the difference:

```
>>> import random
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> testlist = [''.join([chr(random.randint(48, 127)) for _ in range(random.randrange(10, 30))]) for _ in range(1000)]
>>> def str_threevalue_concat(lst):
...     res = ''
...     for elem in lst:
...         res = res + '\n' + elem
... 
>>> def str_twovalue_concat(lst):
...     res = ''
...     for elem in lst:
...         res = res + ('\n%s' % elem)
... 
>>> timeit('f(l)', 'from __main__ import testlist as l, str_threevalue_concat as f', number=10000)
6.196403980255127
>>> timeit('f(l)', 'from __main__ import testlist as l, str_twovalue_concat as f', number=10000)
2.3599119186401367
```

The moral of this story is that you should not be using string concatenation in the first place. The proper way to build a new string from loads of other strings is to use a list, then use `str.join()`:

```
table_rows = []
for something in something_else:
    table_rows += ['\n', GetRow()]
sTable = ''.join(table_rows)
```

This is faster still:

```
>>> def str_join_concat(lst):
...     res = ''.join(['\n%s' % elem for elem in lst])
... 
>>> timeit('f(l)', 'from __main__ import testlist as l, str_join_concat as f', number=10000)
1.7978830337524414
```

but you cannot beat using just `'\n'.join(lst)`:

```
>>> timeit('f(l)', 'from __main__ import testlist as l, nl_join_concat as f', number=10000)
0.23735499382019043
```

Comment: Huh. So it *was* the string concatenation optimization causing the difference, and the code was just originally written in such a way that the optimization couldn't trigger.