# Increase speed at which HTML table cells are created in Python

Tags: python, html, performance, list, html-table

I have inherited some Python code which is used to create tables of up to 19 columns wide by 5000 rows. Originally, it took the table nine seconds to be drawn on the screen but [I managed to reduce that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25503703/283650) to **six seconds**.

Now I want to optimise it further. I have seen that the bottleneck is, unsurprisingly, the part where the cell contents are created. The code is:

```
sText += '<td align="middle">%s</td>' % sCellContents
```

where `sText` and `sCellContents` are strings. (The style formatting the cell contents can vary.)

If I removed everything but the `<td></td>` tags, the speed is unchanged, implying the styling has no effect on performance. But if I remove those tags (and thereby placing the contents outside the table), the screen is displayed in **three seconds** (though, of course, the formatting is terrible).

Is there any way to optimise that line while preserving the formatting?

I have already tried using lists:

```
lText.append(sCellContents)
```

and then joining at the end:

```
sText = ''.join(lText)
```

but this made no difference.

Comment: Have you tried a template engine like Mako or Jinja2?

Comment: @MFB - no, partly because I'm not familiar with these other options and partly because I don't want to make dramatic (?) changes to the legacy code.

Comment: Fair enough... but spend 2 minutes reading the first few paragraphs of this page: http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/usage.html

Comment: _" it took the table nine seconds to be drawn on the screen"_ out of curiosity, how did you identified the bottleneck a being in "generating HTML" rather than on the "browser side" ? What is the size in byte of your HTML ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux - you mean, how did I know there was a coding issue? There is a comparable tool that loads the data in *three seconds* so I assumed there must be wins to be found in the code!

Comment: @Wikis Have you [profiled](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) your code ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux - no, but that's a great tip, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should give `io.StringIO` a try. It's a stream instead, and might improve performance. Use it like so:

```
s_text_stream = io.StringIO()
s_text_stream.write('<td align="middle">%s</td>' % sCellContents)
s_text_stream.seek(0)
s_text = s_text_stream.read()
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but I am not getting *any* output, will keep trying.

Comment: Sorry, I had to abandon this. Adding `s_text_stream.seek(0)
s_text = s_text_stream.read()` took the load time beyond 20 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Mako](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/usage.html) templates without too much modification to the existing code.

```
from mako.template import Template

t = Template('<td align="middle">${content}</td>')

for cell in sCellContents:
    t.render(content=cell)
```

It would be really interesting to see what difference that makes, if any.

Comment: Sorry, I spent some time trying to set this up but it was not quite a simple as I had hoped.