# What is the different from string's "+" operation between Golang and Python?

Tags: python, go

I found String's "+" operation is so slowly on Go:

```
func main() {
    start := time.Now();
    s := ""
    for i:=0;i<100000;i++ {
        s += "test"
    }
    end := time.Now();
    fmt.Println(end.Sub(start))    //Output 6.495225211s
}
```

But Python:

```
start = datetime.now()

s = ""

for i in range(100000):
    s += 'test'

end = datetime.now()

print(end - start)    # Output 0:00:00.020291
```

I know how to optimize the Go code.
I hope you can tell me why.

thanks.

---

I found a interesting thing on Python:

```
s = ""
for i in range(20):
    s += 'test'
    print(id(s))
```

the output is:

> 139842066321960
>
> 139842066396912
>
> 139842066396912
>
> 139842066400072
>
> 139842066400072
>
> 139842067023232
>
> 139842067023232
>
> 139842066384304
>
> 139842066384304
>
> 139842066312528

Comment: Python has optimised `+=`, avoiding creating a new string object each time; this was done because it is a common error to use `+=` to concatenate strings in a loop. You shouldn't use `+=` if you can avoid it however, use `str.join()` or just `'test' * 100000`.

Comment: See [Why is variable1 += variable2 much faster than variable1 = variable1 + variable2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25503703)

Comment: Presumably go is creating new string objects for each concatenation too. Perhaps go has a string concatenation method that can join multiple strings into one in one step?

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of [How to efficiently concatenate strings in Go?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760757/how-to-efficiently-concatenate-strings-in-go)