# I'm confused by the string method .replace

Tags: python, replace

Why does it happen when i'm replacing a part of a string (a letter actually in the case) in the second case nothing changes

```
in> #first case
in>print('Hello, World!'.replace('l','L'))

out>HeLLo, WorLd!

#second case
a = 'Hello, World!'
a.replace('l','L')
print(a)

out>Hello, World!
```

Comment: Because `replace` doesn't change the existing string. It creates a new version of the string and returns it.

Comment: It's important to understand that python strings are immutable.

Comment: doing this a.replace('l','L') doesn't affect your string 'a', just as Toto said, you have to assign it back to your variable, or to another variable.

Comment: @polku although generally correct of course, CPython sometimes applies an optimization for simple `+=` operations that does mutate the string http://stackoverflow.com/a/25503738/6260170

Answer (score 5):

You have to assign the result of replace to the variable:

```
a = 'Hello, World!'
a = a.replace('l','L')
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace):

> Return a copy of string s with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument maxreplace is given, the first maxreplace occurrences are replaced.

As @Toto mentioned already, you need to return the value.