# understating python builtin function call in context of str.__add__

Tags: python, string, debugging, python-internals

Where can I find what is happening when I run below code

```
"a" + "foo"
```

Basically I am looking for

1. Does above execution call any magic function other than `"a".__add__`(that is `str.__add__`).
2. What is the protocol for `__add__`
3. how to prove its calling `__add__` and not `__eq__`.
4. Is there a debugger python or `gdb` that can step in and prove it is calling `__add__`. Perhaps building python interpreter in debug mode.

Comment: The code you show is **optimised by the Python compiler**, and what Python really runs is `"afoo"`. There is no addition left after the optimizer is done.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking quite a lot here, as this requires a rather deeper understanding of the the specific Python implementation and version used to run the Python code shown.

If we are assuming a recent CPython implementation (the version you'd download from Python.org), then to figure out what Python code does you need to start with the [Python disassembler module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html):

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis('"a" + "foo"')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('afoo')
              2 RETURN_VALUE
```

This shows that the Python compiler has not even bothered to keep the `+` addition around. Instead, the [Python AST optimizer of the compiler](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9458c5c42bbe5fb6ef2393c9ee66f012a2c13ca3/Python/ast_opt.c) has detected that your code is [adding two immutable values](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Python/ast_opt.c#L214-L270) and has instead stored the *result* of the concatenation with the code object. All that remains to be done is load that resulting single value.

If you didn't have such a value, and `a` and `foo` were instead variables, you'd see this:

```
>>> dis.dis('a + foo')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (foo)
              4 BINARY_ADD
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

So addition is implemented as the [`BINARY_ADD` opcode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-BINARY_ADD).

The next step is to look at the [`ceval.c` bytecode evaluation loop](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/767b42633bb7ac39dd6743d8dd7f5b5cc122acea/Python/ceval.c#L1187-L3705) to find [how that opcode is handled](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/767b42633bb7ac39dd6743d8dd7f5b5cc122acea/Python/ceval.c#L1543-L1567):

```c
case TARGET(BINARY_ADD): {
    PyObject *right = POP();
    PyObject *left = TOP();
    PyObject *sum;
    /* NOTE(haypo): Please don't try to micro-optimize int+int on
       CPython using bytecode, it is simply worthless.
       See http://bugs.python.org/issue21955 and
       http://bugs.python.org/issue10044 for the discussion. In short,
       no patch shown any impact on a realistic benchmark, only a minor
       speedup on microbenchmarks. */
    if (PyUnicode_CheckExact(left) &&
             PyUnicode_CheckExact(right)) {
        sum = unicode_concatenate(tstate, left, right, f, next_instr);
        /* unicode_concatenate consumed the ref to left */
    }
    else {
        sum = PyNumber_Add(left, right);
        Py_DECREF(left);
    }
    Py_DECREF(right);
    SET_TOP(sum);
    if (sum == NULL)
        goto error;
    DISPATCH();
}
```

So for anything not a `unicode` object (strings), the [`PyNumber_Add()` C-API function](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/number.html#c.PyNumber_Add) is called. For Python strings, `unicode_concatenate()` is called. The latter is there to [optimize appending to a string in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25503703/why-is-variable1-variable2-much-faster-than-variable1-variable1-variable2/25503738#25503738) (answer written for Python 2, where `unicode_concatenate()` was named `string_concatenate()` instead)) and bypasses the normal code paths used for addition of two objects, but only if both operands are `str` objects, exactly, and not subclasses.

It is `PyNumber_Add()` (implemented in [`abstract.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Objects/abstract.c#L955-L968)) that may trigger a call to `__add__`, but you have to follow the ball carefully as there is a lot of indirection here. `__add__` is the name of the special method **for objects defined in Python code**, but most use is for objects defined in C.

`PyNumber_Add()` calls the general purpose [`binary_op1()` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/767b42633bb7ac39dd6743d8dd7f5b5cc122acea/Objects/abstract.c#L775-L820), which looks for a [`tp_as_number` structure](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_as_number) on the type object of the left operand, which if set is a [`PyNumberMethods` struct](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyNumberMethods), and for addition the `nb_add` entry must be set.

It is `nb_add` that is the C-API equivalent for the `__add__` method on Python types, and it it's the job of the [`typeobject.c` file](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Objects/typeobject.c) to make that mapping. It has this entry:

```c
SLOT1BIN(slot_nb_add, nb_add, "__add__", "__radd__")
```

where `SLOT1BIN` is a [macro that expands to a function implementing the operator](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9458c5c42bbe5fb6ef2393c9ee66f012a2c13ca3/Objects/typeobject.c#L6140-L6179). Just that definition should be enough to confirm that `__add__` will be called, and not `__eq__`, as that's handled by [`tp_richcompare()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9458c5c42bbe5fb6ef2393c9ee66f012a2c13ca3/Objects/typeobject.c#L6632-L6657) instead.